# Reactive @StreamListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

Just a quick one.

Is it possible to have a reactive @StreamListener Input with Spring Cloud Stream? What I mean by that is something like this:

```
@StreamListener
public void log(@Input(Sink.INPUT) Flux<String> strings)
{
    strings.log();
}
```

In the documentation I only saw examples like this:

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void log(String message)
{
    log.info(message);
}
```

or of Processors like this:

```
@StreamListener
@Output(Source.OUTPUT)
public Flux<String> log(@Input(Sink.INPUT) Flux<String> strings)
{
    return strings.map(String::toUpperCase);
}
```

When I run the code from the first snippet I get a `Dispatcher has no subscribers` exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two are equivalent. Open a GitHub issue if you run into errors with it.

EDIT:

The two annotations are equivalent, but the listener will only subscribe to an input if there is a subscription on the input flux. In order to be entirely equivalent, the reactive one should be:

```
@StreamListener
public void log(@Input(Sink.INPUT) Flux<String> strings)
{
    strings.log().subscribe();
}
```

or

```
@StreamListener
public void log(@Input(Sink.INPUT) Flux<String> strings)
{
    strings.subscribe(log::info);
}
```

Simply calling `log()` on the flux creates another `Flux` without a subscription of its own.

Comment: If the first two are equivalent I'll just go with the second snippet, as it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer, adding some more details into why the subscription doesn't take place in the first example.